# How can I assign a fixed value that cannot be deleted in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a TextField in Flutter, I want to set 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' value that cannot be deleted. 
I want to write a value after 'XXXXXXXXXXX' 
So I want a textfield like this

[image: sample TextfieldImage]

How can i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use prefix to show "XXXXXXXXXXXX" before the text field.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Enter the number here",
      prefix: Text("XXXXXXXXXXXX"),
        suffixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
    ),
  onChanged: (str) {
    setState(() {
      _value = "XXXXXXXXXXXX" + str;
    });
  },
),
```